# Why is my text in SVG sometimes rendered at the wrong position?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file with text elements.
The file is [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Powers_of_rotation,_shear,_and_their_compositions.svg) on Wikimedia Commons.

The text I use as an example is:   (s∘r)<sup>2</sup>

```xml
<g style="text-anchor: middle; letter-spacing: -1;" font-size="25px" font-family="sans-serif">
    <text x="500">
        (s∘r)
        <tspan baseline-shift="super" font-size="18px">2</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

Rendered in Image Viewer on Ubuntu it looks like it should. Also when I open it with Inkscape.
In Firefox it looks almost the same, except that `baseline-shift` does not work.
But rendered on Wikimedia Commons it is shifted to the right.
I see no reason for that. <s>(It does not happen to the shorter text elements above.)</s>

[image]

Does the Commons renderer do something wrong?
Or is my code somehow vague enough to allow this?

<s>The `width` and `height` of my SVG is 10 times bigger than the actual size.
Could that be the reason?</s>

**Edit:** The problem is caused by `tspan` tags.
[This](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SVG_text_positioning.svg) file illustrates it more clearly. I asked a [question on Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Graphics_village_pump#SVG_text_with_tspan_tags_is_misplaced).

Comment: Looks like [this problem](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:SVG#Text_transform_limitations). Generally, the [Wikimedia Commons support forum](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Graphics_village_pump) might be a better place to ask about quirks of their software setup.

Comment: Firefox [does not support baseline-shift](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308338)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bug on Commons. https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T97233